# CDI Unit Test fails with unsatisified dependency Exception for Qualifier Type

Tags: unit-testing, mockito, cdi, jboss-weld, cdi-unit

Hi I have a following Qualifier Type defined..

```
@Qualifier
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Target({ ElementType.TYPE, ElementType.FIELD })
public @interface SortAndFilterType {

/**
 * The value for the sort and filter.
 *
 * @return the sort and filter type value.
 */
String value();
}
```

And Two Implementations out of it.

```
@SortAndFilterType("Users")
public class UserSortAndFilterProviderImpl implements SortAndFilterProvider<Field, User>       {}

@SortAndFilterType("ReportsList")
public class ReportListSortAndFilterProviderImpl implements SortAndFilterProvider<Field, ReportList> {}
```

And I'm injecting from the Client as ..

```
@Inject
@SortAndFilterType("Users")
private SortAndFilterProvider mSortAndFilterProvider;
```

Every thing works fine at run time..

But the Problem comes when I ran Unit tests..

I'm getting the below Exception..

> org.jboss.weld.exceptions.DeploymentException: WELD-001408: Unsatisfied dependencies for type SortAndFilterProvider with qualifiers @SortAndFilterType
>     at injection point [BackedAnnotatedField] @Inject @SortAndFilterType private com.collabnet.ctf.saturn.client.apps.users.ChangeUsersStatus.mSortAndFilterProvider

I invoke this from unit tests like this..it runs with @RunWith(CdiRunner.class)

```
@Produces
@SortAndFilterType("Users")
@Mock
private SortAndFilterProvider mSortAndFilterProvider;
```

Whats going wrong here?

Comment: Can you share more code of the test ?

Answer (score 1):

One nice thing with CDI (which is a problem for you here) is that its type safe resolution takes parameter in parameterized types into account. In other word : "no type erasure in CDI"
The spec is very detailed about parameterized types resolution :

> A parameterized bean type is considered assignable to a parameterized
>   required type if they have identical raw type and for each parameter:
>
> - the required type parameter and the bean type parameter are actual types with identical raw type, and, if the type is parameterized, the
>     bean type parameter is assignable to the required type parameter
>     according to these rules, or
> - the required type parameter is a wildcard, the bean type parameter is an actual type and the actual type is assignable to the upper
>     bound, if any, of the wildcard and assignable from the lower bound, if
>     any, of the wildcard, or
> - the required type parameter is a wildcard, the bean type parameter is a type variable and the upper bound of the type variable is
>     assignable to or assignable from the upper bound, if any, of the
>     wildcard and assignable from the lower bound, if any, of the wildcard,
>     or
> - the required type parameter is an actual type, the bean type parameter is a type variable and the actual type is assignable to the
>     upper bound, if any, of the type variable, or
> - the required type parameter and the bean type parameter are both type variables and the upper bound of the required type parameter is
>     assignable to the upper bound, if any, of the bean type parameter.

You can read the original text here : http://docs.jboss.org/cdi/spec/1.2/cdi-spec.html#assignable_parameters.

Now Weld 1.x is not enough strict with this point and accept to assign a parameterized type to its raw type. That's probably why you don't have issue at runtime (running with JBoss AS 7.x for instance) and have this problem in your test (cdi-runner is probably using Weld 2.x). Yes I'm guessing here and I may be wrong, that's why it's always a good thing to give version of framework you're using in your question.

Anyway you should resolve your problem by changing you injection point to

```
@Inject
@SortAndFilterType("Users")
private SortAndFilterProvider<Field,?> mSortAndFilterProvider;
```

It respects the specification and will work under Weld 1.x and 2.x.

By the way you probably don't need your qualifier since there won't be any ambiguity between :

```
@Inject
private SortAndFilterProvider<Field,User> mSortAndFilterProvider1;
```

and

```
@Inject
private SortAndFilterProvider<Field,ReportList> mSortAndFilterProvider2;
```

Comment: Hi That's Exactly the Problem.

Comment: @user1882613, dont forget to validate my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Hi that's Exactly the Problem. and my Runtime uses Jboss 7 and the Test Environment uses CDI 2.x.

After adding the type parameters to the Injection point it works perfectly fine.

Thanks a lot.

Comment: So perhaps you could validate my answer ;)